# How to manage squid authentication

Tags: proxy, authentication, squid

I'm running a squid server.

I want to limit my users for using their usernames to use my proxy server.
For example, I define a limit for a username named (user1) that if, for example, 3 devices use this username at the same time to connect and use the proxy server, no one else can use that username to connect to proxy server and use it until one of the three users stop using proxy.

Is there any way for me to do that?

Excuse me in advance if my problem was not understandable and the way I explained it wasn't good enough...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with squid.

You can set a maximum number of IP addresses for a user (see the `max_user_ip` [acltype](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/acl/)) but there's no logout mechanism for http/proxy auth.

At least, there's no consistent or reliable mechanism.  Some browsers make it easy to forget auth credentials, most do not...it's not as if http auth is used much these days, everyone uses some sort of login page and cookies for authentication.  http auth was extremely annoying even back in the mid 90s when it was used because it was the only option commonly available, before anyone thought about or implemented user session management for web sites to work around the stateless nature of the web.

Even if it were possible, you'd have problems with users forgetting or not bothering to log out, or being unable to logout because they logged in at their desktop machine and now they're miles away on their laptop or tablet.

So, there's no logout button.

There is, however, a time-to-live (ttl) setting [authenticate_ip_ttl](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/authenticate_ip_ttl/) - so that when a user authenticates, the authorisation will be valid for X number of seconds.

Solution: set `max_user_ip` to 3, and `authenticate_ip_ttl` to 3600 seconds or so (1 hour).  That should be enough time for people to use the proxy without being constantly annoyed by auth requests while they're actively using a device to browse, but short enough that their logins on other devices will time out reasonably quickly.

Excerpts from squid.conf example:

```
#   acl aclname max_user_ip [-s] number
#     # This will be matched when the user attempts to log in from more
#     # than <number> different ip addresses. The authenticate_ip_ttl
#     # parameter controls the timeout on the ip entries. [fast]
#     # If -s is specified the limit is strict, denying browsing
#     # from any further IP addresses until the ttl has expired. Without
#     # -s Squid will just annoy the user by "randomly" denying requests.
#     # (the counter is reset each time the limit is reached and a
#     # request is denied)
#     # NOTE: in acceleration mode or where there is mesh of child proxies,
#     # clients may appear to come from multiple addresses if they are
#     # going through proxy farms, so a limit of 1 may cause user problems.


#  TAG: authenticate_ip_ttl
#   If you use proxy authentication and the 'max_user_ip' ACL,
#   this directive controls how long Squid remembers the IP
#   addresses associated with each user.  Use a small value
#   (e.g., 60 seconds) if your users might change addresses
#   quickly, as is the case with dialup.   You might be safe
#   using a larger value (e.g., 2 hours) in a corporate LAN
#   environment with relatively static address assignments.
#Default:
# authenticate_ip_ttl 1 second
```